# Why does my do while loop keep going?

Tags: java, do-while

I'm trying to do a simple Hangman game for school.

In the beginning the user inputs a word as a String and the string is converted into a char Array, wordArray. Then a char Array starArray is created that has the same amount of elements as wordArray, and is filled with "*". Those start get replaced with letters as the letters are guessed correctly.

After this, I have this loop:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Guess a letter:");
    strGuess = scan.nextLine();
    chGuess = strGuess.charAt(0); 
    //prompts the user to guess a letter and converts said letter to a char

            for(int i = 0; i<Array.getLength(wordArray); i++){
                if (chGuess == wordArray[i]){
                     starArray[i] = strGuess.charAt(0);
                     guessCorrect = true;
                    }
            }   //this happens if the guess is correct

            if (guessCorrect == false){
                System.out.println("Nope, wrong guess!");
                 wrongGuess = wrongGuess + 1;
                 System.out.println("You have " + (5-wrongGuess) + " lives left.");
            } //if the guess isn't correct, amount of wrong guesses increases

            guessCorrect = false; //the value of whether a guess is correct resets

            for(int i=0;i<starArray.length;i++){
                System.out.print(starArray[i]);
            } //prints out the word with "*" in place of letters that haven't been guessed yet

           /*if starArray == wordArray
            wordGuessed = true;*/

    } while (wrongGuess == 5 || wordGuessed == false); //if the word is guessed or the user has guessed wrong 5 times, the loop ends
```

Now this code isn't complete yet, so the "wordGuessed" part of the condition can never happen as of now - you can't win the game yet. However, the loop doesn't end when the wrongGuess value gets higher than 5. It will keep going, prompting the user to guess again and again. I checked and the wordGuessed value does in fact change correctly, do it does reach 5 after 5 wrong guesses.

Comment: Did you mean `wrongGuess < 5` instead of `wrongGuess == 5` ?

Comment: `|| wordGuessed == false` value never changes

Comment: Nothing in your loop changes the value of `wordGuessed`, so why would you expect your loop to ever terminate?

Comment: To Berger - I don't think it really matters as it only changes the max value wrongGuess can reach. As of now, my wrongGuess can reach 50 if I guess the same wrong letter 50 times in a row. I changed the "==" in my code to "<" just to see if something changes and it still doesn't work.

To Anurag: Yep, I'm aware, that part isn't the part I'm concerned about.

Comment: But isn't the || an "OR" operator? Meaning that EITHER  wordGuessed is true, OR wrongGuess is equal to 5?

Comment: As it is, what you're asking does not make sense. You're asking why your loop doesn't end, and all anyone can do is point out that your loop condition doesn't make sense, which you already know. So what do you expect?

Comment: You need to concat your conditions with `&&` and somewhere `wordGuessed` should be set to `true`. You loop as long as this condition is `true`.

Comment: It’s an aside, seasoned programmers will prefer `! wordGuessed` over `wordGuessed == false`.

Answer (score 2):

If `wordGuessed` is always false, `wordGuessed == false` will always return true.

The condition to loop is that `wrongGuess == 5 || wordGuessed == false` is true.
Using the first statement, that could be replaced by: `wrongGuess == 5 || true`

That will also always be true as `anything OR true` is true.

You want to **stop** looping **once** (`wrongGuess == 5` or `wordGuessed == true`).
In other words, **loop while** `!((wrongGuess == 5) OR (wordGuessed == true))`.

Basic boolean algebra, the reverse of **A OR B** is **!A AND !B**. You have to keep looping while `wrongGuess != 5 && wordGuessed == false`